# nginx rewrite with index configuration error

Tags: nginx

We have virtual server settings below. We hope that when visiting `/doc/`, nginx will auto visit `/doc/index.html`, and use the static file `/data/doc/site/index.html` to serve.

```
server {
        listen 8123 default_server;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location /doc {
                root /data/doc/site;
                index index.html;
                rewrite /doc(.*) $1 break;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass_header Server;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7001;  // !!!not exists!!!
        }
}
```

But,

```
$ curl http://192.168.1.230:8123/doc/ -v
*   Trying 192.168.1.230...
* Connected to 192.168.1.230 (192.168.1.230) port 8123 (#0)
> GET /doc/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.230:8123
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 21 Dec 2015 07:37:29 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 181
< Connection: keep-alive
<
```

and

```
$ curl http://192.168.1.230:8123/doc/index.html -v
*   Trying 192.168.1.230...
* Connected to 192.168.1.230 (192.168.1.230) port 8123 (#0)
> GET /doc/index.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.230:8123
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 21 Dec 2015 07:33:47 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 11
< Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Dec 2015 06:51:07 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5677a15b-b"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
root index
```

It seems that after rewrite, nginx rematch the changed URL for a new location. But in the doc, it says

```
last
stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI;
break
stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives as with the break directive;
```

It shouldn't search for a new location matching the changed URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `alias`.

```
location /doc/ {
    alias /data/doc/site/;
    index index.html;
}
```

Your code with `rewrite` isn't working because `index` does internal redirect. So request flow in your case is: `/doc/` → (rewrite) `/` → (index, internal redirect) `/index.html` → (proxy_pass)

Comment: BTW, in which situation will you use rewrite?

Comment: And also, why are the rewrite not working here?

Comment: @hbprotoss added some explanation

Comment: You are awesome! :)